# Using column value if column exist

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to select the values from column, if the column exist.

This table is going under some modification and some columns are removed and values are extracted to another table.

Query I am using is below. At this stage column can be presented or may be already dropped, so I am doing a column check

```
IF COL_LENGTH('MyTableName', 'MyColumnName') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO SOMETABLE VALUES(TITLE,TYPEID)
    SELECT DISTINCT MyColumnName,2
    FROM MyTableName
END
```

Also tried

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns 
          WHERE Name = N'MyColumnName'
          AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'dbo.MyTableName'))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO SOMETABLE VALUES(TITLE,TYPEID)
    SELECT DISTINCT MyColumnName,2
    FROM MyTableName
END
```

But this give me error when the Column is dropped even with the column exist check

*Invalid column name 'MyColumnName'*

Is there a way to get around this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect the error originates during the compiling of the query. The compiler doesn't consider `IF` statements, it evaluates the whole query as if everything is to be executed. When a non-existing column is encountered you get an error, regardless of whether you checked for existence. I think the best solution is to use dynamic SQL to get around that.

Something like:

```
IF COL_LENGTH('MyTableName', 'MyColumnName') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO SOMETABLE VALUES(TITLE,TYPEID)
                             SELECT DISTINCT MyColumnName,2
                             FROM MyTableName'
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns 
          WHERE Name = N'MyColumnName'
          AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'dbo.MyTableName'))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO SOMETABLE VALUES(TITLE,TYPEID)
    SELECT DISTINCT MyColumnName,2
    FROM MyTableName
END
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention in question. I tried this as well but with same result